# How to pass value from querystring to action class in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I want to pass ID from query string to my action class, and want to use that id in my action class. I tried as:

```
<li>
  <a href="NextPageData.action?recordID=sessionMap.get(recordID[0])">Next</a>
</li>
```

but I am getting exception. I have aaded list to sessionMap and want to retrive that value from sessionMap as queryString parameter.
Can anybody provide me solution for this problem
Thanks.

Comment: can u show the code and exception

Comment: Why do you need this parameter in the action?

Answer (score 0):

If you kept in session there is no need to send as request parameter again.You can directly access that session variable in Action class.

Comment: Don't do that. Your actions are not stateless any longer. If a user calls your actions from differnt tabs, confusion will arise.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in Struts2 request parameters are automatically available in the action if:

1. You have a getter and setter in your action for a variable with the same name (eg int getRecordID() setRecordID(int id) in your case)
2. You have the ParametersInterceptor in the action's interceptor stack. [1]

[1] See http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/interceptors.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
<li>
  <a href="NextPageData.action?recordID="+<s:property value="%{sessionMap.get(recordID[0])}/> >Next</a>
</li>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not a Struts expert, but I tried the following my Struts 2 Live  project and its working fine.

```
String paramValue = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("paramName");
```

Comment: You don't really need to do this in S2. And this is probably not what OP asks.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put this code on action class.

```
String paramValue = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("recordID");
```